# Python: Flatten a list of Objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, flatmap

I have a list of Objects and each object has inside it a list of other object type. I want to extract those lists and create a new list of the other object.

```
List1:[Obj1, Obj2, Obj3]

Obj1.myList = [O1, O2, O3]
Obj2.myList = [O4, O5, O6]
Obj3.myList = [O7, O8, O9]
```

I need this:

`L = [O1, O2, O3, O4, ...., O9];`

I tried `extend()` and `reduce()` but didn't work

```
bigList = reduce(lambda acc, slice: acc.extend(slice.coresetPoints.points), self.stack, [])
```

P.S.

Looking for python flatten a list of list didn't help as I got a list of lists of other object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using `itertools.chain` (or even better in that case `itertools.chain.from_iterable` as niemmi noted) which avoids creating temporary lists and using `extend`

```
import itertools
print(list(itertools.chain(*(x.myList for x in List1))))
```

or (much clearer and slightly faster):

```
print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x.myList for x in List1)))
```

small reproduceable test:

```
class O:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

Obj1,Obj2,Obj3 = [O() for _ in range(3)]

List1 = [Obj1, Obj2, Obj3]

Obj1.myList = [1, 2, 3]
Obj2.myList = [4, 5, 6]
Obj3.myList = [7, 8, 9]

import itertools
print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x.myList for x in List1)))
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

(all recipes to flatten a list of lists: [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists))

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that with one-line [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[i for obj in List1 for i in obj.myList]
```

Answer (score 0):

`list.extend()` returns `None`, not a list. You need to use concatenation in your lambda function, so that the result of the function call is a list:

```
bigList = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y.myList, List1, [])
```

While this is doable with `reduce()`, using a list comprehension would be both faster and more pythonic:

```
bigList = [x for obj in List1 for x in obj.myList]
```

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly rocket science:

```
L = []
for obj in List1:
    L.extend(obj.myList)
```