# How to convert list of dictionaries to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
mylist = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'e': 5, 'f': 6}]
```

i want it as

```
myDict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}
```

Comment: Start with checking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521431/python-flatten-a-list-of-objects) out, and then ask specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: i have edited the question.now its is very clear to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of [ChainMap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap).

```
from collections import ChainMap
myDict = dict(ChainMap(*mylist))
```

Comment: ChainMap is better because it skips most of the work you'd have to do to construct a new dict and copy all the values. But if you force it to do that anyway, maybe just make an update loop? Can OP use the ChainMap directly instead of forcing it to a dict?

Answer (score 0):

This will take each dictionary and iterate through its key value pairs in `for (k,v) in elem.items()` part and assign them to a new dictionary.

```
mylist = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'e': 5, 'f': 6}]
new_dict = {k:v for elem in mylist for (k,v) in elem.items()}
print new_dict
```

This will replace the duplicated keys.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new dictionary, iterate over the dictionaries in `mylist`, then iterate over the key/value pairs in that dictionary. From there, you can add each key/value pair to `myDict`.

```
mylist = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'e': 5, 'f': 6}]
myDict = {}

for d in mylist:
    for key in d:
        myDict[key] = d[key]

print(myDict)
```